# First eigenvalue of the Laplacian on a regular polygon

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, sp.spectral-theory, laplacian

Consider the Laplacian eigenvalue problem $-\Delta u = \lambda u$ on $\Omega$ with Dirichlet boundary conditions. Let $\lambda_1$ denote the first eigenvalue. The following theorem is well known:

(Faber-Krahn) Let $c$ be a positive number and $B$ the ball of volume $c$. Then
$$\lambda_1(B) = \min\{\lambda_1(\Omega), \Omega\ \text{open subset of}\ \mathbb{R}^n, 
|\Omega| = c\}.$$

I am considering the question of minimizing $\lambda_1$ in the class of polygons with a given number $N$ as sides. If we denote by $\mathcal{P}_N$ the class of plane polygons with at most $N$ edges, then it is known that the problem
$$\min\{\lambda_1(\Omega), \Omega \in \mathcal{P}_N, |\Omega| = a\}$$
has a solution. This one has exactly $N$ edges.
For the case $N=3$, it has been proven the equilateral triangle minimizes $\lambda_1$. For $N=4$, the square minimizes $\lambda_1$. (Both proof uses the properties of the Steiner symmetrization of $\Omega$. The original proof was due to Pólya. Unfortuantely I could not find the original paper, but the proof can also be found in *Extremum problems for Eigenvalues of Elliptic Operators* by Henrot.)

Question: Is there a general result that the regular $N$-gon have the least first eigenvalue among all the $N$-gons of given area for $N \geq 5$?

Comment: Can you include, in your question, the literature for N = 3,4?

Comment: I edited the question :)

Comment: This is well known to be open. I think that the $N=3,4$ cases can be found in Polya and Szego's book "Isoperimetric Inequalities in Mathematical Physics." But the proof is not hard if you know that Steiner symmetrization decreases the first eigenvalue.

Comment: @WillieWong The  case $n=3,4$ was proven by Polya. See, for instance Henrot's [paper](https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/hal-00115548/file/jeelong.pdf). As far as I understand, for $n\geq 5$, Steiner symmetrization method increases the number of sides.

Answer (score 8):

For $N \geq 5$ it is still not known if the $N$-gon which minimizes the first eigenvalue under area constraint (which exists), is the regular one. I have done some numerical computations which suggest that the regular polygons are indeed optimal. You can see the numerical ideas [here](http://www.lama.univ-savoie.fr/~bogosel/faber_krahn_polygons.html) (recent version) or [here](https://mathproblems123.wordpress.com/2013/12/23/numerical-method-minimizing-eigenvalues-on-polygons/) (old version).

Answer (score 4):

So few people are working on this problem. I have noticed that results are scattered far and wide. So, I am calculating and compiling data related to the eigenvalues of the Laplacian within polygons. For example, below is a list of the principal Dirichlet eigenvalues within regular polygons (with area Pi, not inscribe in a unit-radius circle), all correctly rounded to 27 decimal places. I actually bounded them to within a relative error of at most 1E-30; and the pentagon, I have to 1E-500. But, below is a good list. The first two are known in closed form, and the last entry is the square of the first root of the Bessel function J_0(x)=0. This last one is the number the sequence is approaching. One can use the formula L = j01^2*(1+4*zeta(3)/N^3+ O(1/N^5)) to estimate the eigenvalue, with improving results as N (the number of polygon sides) increases. I do not use that formula, and I challenge anyone to figure out the non-zero fifth order term. (Incidentally, each eigenvalue shown from 127 sides and up takes about a day of CPU time. I'm doing the 256 sided polygon now, but I can't get thirty digits. I'm at only about 20 digits now, 
5.7831876203689428759... where the trailing digits are yet uncertain.) -Bob Jones

3    7.255197456936871402376313031 <--- 4*Pi/sqrt(3)

   4    6.283185307179586476925286767 <--- 2*Pi

   5    6.022137932042633878298008710

   6    5.917417831613661215688574577

   7    5.866449312655985857712474942

   8    5.838491433592442850516640380

   9    5.821826802270265731735546444

  10    5.811260359219116022788816469

  11    5.804230636717400721878394453

  12    5.799369804356500079315025311

  13    5.795900266856014709790771063

  14    5.793357005271194553273227079

  15    5.791450010651579975693848498

  16    5.789991899990208534349752214

  17    5.788857871981104698617196635

  18    5.787962591857846864212568380

  19    5.787246351381961243008036645

  20    5.786666514140372213530912962

  21    5.786192077596844273028203757

  22    5.785800129428365027574586044

  23    5.785473486454901632048264070

  24    5.785199089790024091834463613

  25    5.784966894130423501418670684

  26    5.784769086314842977992274718

  27    5.784599527236484640593222827

  28    5.784453347751719951196794842

  29    5.784326652365411207380293386

  30    5.784216299392264044119036734

  31    5.784119736080032703344528385

  32    5.784034873702444318330507487

  33    5.783959992040508812335032523

  34    5.783893665694809252033476569

  35    5.783834706770988202840700005

  36    5.783782119955880627699919966

  37    5.783735067049846291962440637

  38    5.783692838773292267706517922

  39    5.783654832210871143386207911

  40    5.783620532655973576951368559

  41    5.783589498912728857243541088

  42    5.783561351331960679963744950

  43    5.783535762021971971277446762

  44    5.783512446799268033474803358

  45    5.783491158538856302913858879

  46    5.783471681656168110105137225

  47    5.783453827508463297379645914

  48    5.783437430546865419250636065

  49    5.783422345083940177286945517

  50    5.783408442568212994780116196

  51    5.783395609277903442166398140

  52    5.783383744362702700019559015

  53    5.783372758175598244048049661

  54    5.783362570847292742897314144

  55    5.783353111064236385644810842

  56    5.783344315018129354638447816

  57    5.783336125500292103090369355

  58    5.783328491118809153913672275

  59    5.783321365620033853737939611

  60    5.783314707299059428210797800

  61    5.783308478486244250571058736

  62    5.783302645098928410170380598

  63    5.783297176249175699422050587

  64    5.783292043899785027461125829

  65    5.783287222561990216101379319

  66    5.783282689029249211147849046

  67    5.783278422142346980297970170

  68    5.783274402581728387648667337

  69    5.783270612683560625466506793

  70    5.783267036276517720104953505

  71    5.783263658536697267505357057

  72    5.783260465858434270390794564

  73    5.783257445739078946040870361

  74    5.783254586676063084321584559

  75    5.783251878074799951907284413

  76    5.783249310166151671634629193

  77    5.783246873932360298530618523

  78    5.783244561040478512305563119

  79    5.783242363782456338656120879

  80    5.783240275021144443460263290

  81    5.783238288141564708788818914

  82    5.783236397006877016631166830

  83    5.783234595918539141935169159

  84    5.783232879580215836619574007

  85    5.783231243065044797761869160

  86    5.783229681785912299987294190

  87    5.783228191468430723800997531

 127    5.783199538123680412174552014

 128    5.783199222432098956985238320

 129    5.783198916453726829015452454

 130    5.783198619817847494322697718

        5.783185962946784521175995758 <-- j_{0,1}^2 (J_0(j_{0,1})=0)

Comment: The subject per se might be useful, but this is probably not the right place to "publish" this result.

Comment: Thanks, but I read this:"Thanks for contributing an answer to MathOverflow! Please be sure to answer the question. Provide details and share your research! But avoid … Asking for help, clarification, or responding to other answers. Making statements based on opinion; back them up with references or personal experience...." and thought I was being helpful and relevant about the question. --Bob

Comment: I believe this is an update to the answer of @user122986: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1602.08636v1.pdf

Answer (score 2):

Some recent activity on the problem:

Results regarding the Hessian matrix with respect to vertex coordinates, numerical local minimality estimates and analytical bounds on the diameter of the optimal polygon can be found in https://arxiv.org/pdf/2203.16409.pdf   In particular, the conjecture is reduced to a finite number of numerical computations.

This paper also deals with the same problem: https://arxiv.org/abs/2210.14806. A polygonal manifold is constructed in which the regular one is optimal.